# Is it possible to remove labels from lightning:progressIndicator?

Tags: lightning, lightning-progressindicator

I've searched everywhere but can't find a solution to remove the labels on the step..

```
<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.currentStep}" type="base" hasError="false" variant="base">
                <lightning:progressStep value="1" onclick="{!c.changeStep}" id="1"/>
                <lightning:progressStep value="2" onclick="{!c.changeStep}" id="2"/>
                <lightning:progressStep value="3" onclick="{!c.changeStep}" id="3"/>
            </lightning:progressIndicator>
```

This is my progressIndicator. I'm unable to remove the label from every progressStep; if i remove those labels manually, when i move the cursor above the step it shows me a blank label like this
[image]

How can i remove completely these labels?

Comment: can you explain your use case? lightning:progressStep tag which is used inside the lightning:progressIndicator have label attribute which will fill your ask.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use native SLDS?

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">

  <div class="slds-progress">
  <ol class="slds-progress__list">
    <li class="slds-progress__item slds-is-active">
      <button class="slds-button slds-progress__marker">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Step 1 - Active</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-progress__item">
      <button class="slds-button slds-progress__marker">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Step 2 </span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-progress__item">
      <button class="slds-button slds-progress__marker">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Step 3 </span>
      </button>
    </li>

  </ol>
    </div>

</aura:application>
```

SLDS Progress Indicator has the bare minimum that you need.

Src: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator/

Comment: I've found what I've used here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator/example. If there is a way, i prefer this one i've used because if I change using the one you suggest, I have to change all the logic behind it.. why have i to change all instead of removing only a label? I'm gonna use this solution if  none knows how to do.. but for now i'll wait a day..thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hide the lightning:progressStep tooltips by NOT adding the label attribute to the tag and applying the following component CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-popover_tooltip {
   display:none;
}
```